# I want to change the column value for a specific index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt',dtype=str)
print(df)

    HE   WE
0   aa  NaN
1  181   76
2   22   13
3  NaN  NaN
```

I want to overwrite any of these data frames with the following indexes

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'HE' : [100,30]},index=[1,2])
print(dff)

    HE
1  100
2   30

for i in dff.index:
    df._set_value(i,'HE',dff._get_value(i,'HE'))

print(df)

    HE   WE
0   aa  NaN
1  100   76
2   30   13
3  NaN  NaN
```

Is there a way to change it all at once without using 'for'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), (working inplace):

```
df.update(dff)
print (df)
    HE    WE
0   aa   NaN
1  100  76.0
2   30  13.0
3  NaN   NaN
```